# ARK dedicated server without internet?

Tags: hosting, ark-survival-evolved

Is it possible on the same PC to host a server through ARK Server Manager, and play on that server without internet access?

Without internet, the server will not show up in ARK’s server browser, even when filtered for LAN. Trying to join through Steam’s server browser doesn’t work either, the game starts up, then displays;

> Unable to query server info for invite

With internet I can join. My PC uses Ethernet.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you already know this but, Steam **requires** to internet to play online games.

Ark's server will firstly connect through Steam's [master server](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/features/multiplayer/game_servers) to be shown on the server browser(either Steam's server browser and Ark's server browser), so that any steam user can find your (or, others) server from anywhere.

Since your server can't connect to Steam master server, the game cannot receive any info from it, so it refuses to connect. I don't know what would happen if you gone completely offline, but my bet is that you can't even select connect to multi player server.

Or maybe perhaps you can connect through console. When you start your Ark, hit `Tab` to open console, and then type `open 127.0.0.1:7777` (or whatever port you've forwarded), and hit `Enter`. I don't know if it works, but maybe give it a shot.

Comment: I’ve tried that command too, but it displays an error saying connection timed out. And you can get to the server selection screen when you’re disconnected.

Comment: @HyperBlend Well then my answer would be: No, you will need internet connection to enter the Ark's dedicated server.